# Passing value from one form to a textbox in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

Well I know this question has been asked a couple of times but none of the solutions worked for me. I simply want to pass a value from one form to a textbox in a different form.
On the first form I have a data grid when double-clicked on it obtains a value from the datagrid column.

```
public partial class AvailableRooms : Form
{   
   private void DCRoom(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) 
  {
   var roomnum = dgRooms.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["iRoomNum"].Value.ToString();
   RoomBooking rb = new RoomBooking();//The second form
   rb.roomnumber = roomnum;           
   rb.Show();        
 }
}
```

On the second form I have set the properties of the textbox

```
public partial class RoomBooking : Form
{

   public RoomBooking()
    {
      StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
      InitializeComponent();
  }

  public string roomnumber
   {
      get { return txtRoomNum.Text; }
      set {txtRoomNum.Text = value;}
    }

 }
```

Thanks in advance for the help?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having or error you're seeing?

Comment: Your code seems to work OK, what is the actual problem?

Comment: When the 'RoomBooking' form pops up the txtRoomNum textbox is blank.No value has been passed to it even after assigning it a value 'rb.roomnumber = roomnum;'

Comment: @MichaelGoyote did you check the value of `roomnum`?

Comment: have u put a breakpoint and checked what is happening?

Comment: Yeah I did when inserting a breaking point at the editor, `roomnum` has the correct selected data

Comment: are you handling any change events of textbox like `TextChanged` and changing its value based on some condition?

Comment: I think you should set some breakpoint at `txtRoomNum.Text = value;` and run for next steps then... even add `txtRoomNum.Text` as a watch to see the moment it changes to empty string.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel No am not doing any change events

Comment: Ok do this exercise, subscribe `TextChanged` event of txtRoonNum and put a breakpoint over there. then run your app and see how many times it fires, you can check txtRoonNum.Text inside the event handler to make sure what is the current value. you can catch the culprit easily when `txtRoonNum.Text` property returns empty just open `CallStack` window to see who resets it to Empty

Comment: Finally It worked, I can't tell exactly what the issue was, I deleted the bin folder, rebuilt the solution now its running fine. Thanks for the help. I thought there was something wrong with the code.

Comment: @MichaelGoyote it's obvious that the old `.exe` was run instead of the current version, this kind of issue sometimes happens and `Rebuild` is the first must-try thing we can do to sort it out.

Comment: And i definitely learnt a little troubleshooting procedure from @SriramSakthivel

Comment: @MichaelGoyote Cheers now you learnt to debug. keep going

Comment: 'rb.roomnumber = (string)roomnum;'?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the control to edit it as it does not belong to the class.

```
private void DCRoom(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    //new value
    var roomnum = dgRooms.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["iRoomNum"].Value.ToString();
    //The second form
    RoomBooking rb = new RoomBooking(this);
    //The textbox
    TextBox roomnumber = (TextBox)rb.Controls.Find("roomnumber", true)[0];
    //set the value of the textbox
    roomnumber.Text = roomnum;
    //show second form
    rb.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define the `RoomBooking`class like this:

```cs
public partial class RoomBooking : Form
{
    public RoomBooking() // WinForms Designer requires a public parameterless constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }

    public RoomBooking(string roomNumber) : this() // Constructor chaining
    {
        RoomNumber = roomNumber;
        txtRoomNum.Text = RoomNumber;
    }

    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```cs
public partial class AvailableRooms : Form
{      
    private void DCRoom(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var roomNumber = dgRooms.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["iRoomNum"].Value.ToString();
        var roomBooking = new RoomBooking(roomNumber);
        roomBooking.Show();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well this certainly look like a cleaner way of doing it. Will try and let you know.

Comment: I've been using this sort of pattern with success in the project I am currently working on. Also - if you just need `txtRoomNum` to be set once, and plan to reference that instead of the `RoomNumber` property, then you can remove said property from the class definition and set `txtRoomNum.Text = roomNumber`directly.